# Restrict Client side validation for 1 case and enable for other case in same screen(cshtml) MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a view which has several input fields(textboxes and dropdowns) and this is an edit screen and the data for the input elements are loaded from the DB. I need to perform client side validation here when the user saves the form.And this works perfect!

On another case(case: 2), I need to load the same screen with data from DB but I dont need to have a client validation here.  (difference between case 1 and case 2 is a text box value)

So how do i perform client side validation on case where particular textbox value is "A" and restrict client validations from happening when the particular textbox has value other than "A".

1. Is it possible?
2. Or Is it advisable to have 2 screens for these 2 cases. But my model class structure is same for both cases decorated with validation attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put textbox value in Viewbag from Controller and disable client validations on view with condition as :-

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
Public ActionResult YourAction()
{
   //get data from db and bind to model
     Viewbag.textvalue=....//Some Value...
     return View(model);
}
```

View :

```
@{
  if(Viewbag.textvalue!="A"){
  HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
  }
}
```

### NOTE:

Above code will disable client validation on complete form depending upon textbox value as specified in your question.